# How to create horizontal RecyclerView that auto new line when screen space is full?

Tags: android, tags, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use RecyclerView to display programmatically tags in my app. It would like this(sorry, i can't upload image to stackoverflow now)

http://anh.im/image/OUA

So, how can i create RecyclerView that show my contents left to right and auto new line at the right edge of RecyclerView look like the image and prevent it scroll horizontally? Thanks for any help!

Comment: The arrangement in the image is a bit confusing. The items are sorted alphabetical from top to bottom, but you want to make it scroll horizontal?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Don't get confused about it's arrangement. I just want to show my tags from my ArrayList left to right and auto break line(enter/new line...) at the right edge of the RecyclerView and prevent it scroll horizontal

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: @AnhPham finally have you achieved to do this?

Comment: Not yet. I'm even not develop Android apps anymore. sorry...

Answer (score 5):

Use
**implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'**

Just add in your recyclerview

```
 val decoration = DividerItemDecoration(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL)
    decoration.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.divider_10dp)!!)
    recyclerViewSelectionList.addItemDecoration(decoration)
    val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(this)
    layoutManager.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
    layoutManager.justifyContent = JustifyContent.FLEX_START
    recyclerViewSelectionList.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

Comment: This is Java code :-
 
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager =new FlexboxLayoutManager(mContext);
        layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
        layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
        recyclerViewSelectionList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Answer (score 1):

### Update 10/2022:

Use `implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'`.
It's work for me!

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

### xml solution:

Add `implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'` to your app build.gradle.

Then add the layoutManager to your RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:adapter="@{viewModel.adapter}" // Only if you set the adapter with data binding
    app:layoutManager="com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager" />
```